# Xamarin (сборка на Андроид) ошибка компилятора

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

При сборке приложения компилятор кидает ошибку

```html
непредвиденная ошибка при выполнении задачи CreateNativeLibraryArchive".
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Файл 'Lib\arm64-v8a\libprocex.so' не найден.
Имя файла: 'Lib\arm64-v8a\libprocex.so'
   в System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   в System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   в System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
   в Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfChanged(String source, String destination)
   в Xamarin.Android.Tasks.CreateNativeLibraryArchive.Execute()
   в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() ChessUI
```

Чистил все bin b оbj, последнее обновление VS

Поддерживаемые архитектуры все доступные в VS
armeabi
armeabi v7A
X86
x86_64
arm64-v8a

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том что, что проект использовал сторонние сборки, и для сборки главного проекта необходимы были файлы для каждой из вышеперечисленных архитектур, для их сборки в свою очередь нужен был ANdroid NDK. После его корректной установки (без пробелов) все заработало и собралось.